# How do I install most recent MongoDB version on Raspberry-Pi (Model B+)?

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi

I've read this [tutorial](http://c-mobberley.com/wordpress/2013/10/14/raspberry-pi-mongodb-installation-the-working-guide/), however the version that is available to clone is MongoDB 2.1.1. Can I use the most recent of Mongo following the official installation guide for Debian or should I use the Linux Systems generic guide?

Comment: I've made a simple auto install script here: https://github.com/vcazan/MongoDB-RPi-Install